# How to download a Blob using a SAS

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I'm trying to use AzCopy 5.1.0 to download a *single* blob from a Blob Storage container using a SAS generated by Storage Explorer:

`https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/[blob-uuid]?st=2016-11-23T18%3A26%3A00Z&se=2016-11-24T18%3A26%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=[signature]`

```
azcopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /SourceSAS:"?st=2016-11-23T18%3A26%3A00Z&se=2016-11-24T18%3A26%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=[signature]" /Dest:"c:\data"
```

If /Source is supposed to be the blob container, and the /SourceSAS is supposed to be the SAS *token*, then somewhere I need to pass in the actual Blob key ([blob-uuid]).

IMHO, this should be /SourceKey, but specifying my blob key there returns the error: "The supplied storage key (SourceKey) is not a valid Base64 string." This is consistent with the command line help that describes the parameter as the "Storage account key".

The only other candidate I can find is /Pattern, but that seems more for the case of downloading blobs by enumerating through the contents of the container. This seems consistent with the 403 error I get when I specify the exact blob key here; the container is private.

In any case, AzCopy complains that the "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature." This in my experience indicates that the original URI that the SAS signature was generated upon, is not being reconstructed properly.

I am able to use the original SAS URI directly via curl, so it's not a question of the signature being inconsistent.

I've also tried generating the SAS URI programmatically using the SDK so I can specify a Shared Access Policy, but that's not working either. I still think AzCopy needs the missing part of the SAS URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AzCopy transfer target is always a directory, not a single blob/file, so AzCopy need container level SAS instead of blob SAS. 
The pattern is only used to filter out the objects to transfer.

We will open a task to track download a single blob with blob SAS. Anyway, this is not aligned with current AzCopy logic, we will take it as a new feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#blob-download):

> Download single blob:

```
AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /Dest:C:\myfolder /SourceKey:key /Pattern:"abc.txt"
```

`/Source` would be your URI up to the container

`/SourceKey` would be your key, but without the question mark at the begining

`/Pattern` would be the name of your blob

`/Destination` would be the local folder name where you want the blob to be downloaded

Comment: Are you suggesting the "key" for the /SourceKey parameter is the SAS Token without the preceding question mark? Because that causes the same error I described: "The supplied storage key (SourceKey) is not a valid Base64 string"

The command-line help: azcopy /?:SourceKey describes the parameter thusly: `/SourceKey:<storage-key> Specifies the storage account key for the source resource.` which is consistent with the error message, but not consistent with the overall download operation.

Comment: What astaykov wrote above is correct, but let me clarify more for your example, you can call AzCopy like this: azcopy /Source:https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /SourceSAS:"?st=2016-11-23T18%3A26%3A00Z&se=2016-11-24T18%3A26%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=[signature]" /Dest:"c:\data" /Pattern:"[blob-uuid]"

Comment: Per "sr=b", you're using a blob SAS rather than container SAS, so please make sure your AzCopy has been upgraded to latest version since old AzCopy doesn't support blob SAS as source SAS.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft I'm using AzCopy 5.1.0 which is the latest version I can find (http://aka.ms/downloadazcopy). The project doesn't appear to be on GitHub anymore, either.

Do you know if Blob SAS support is coming in a new version that has yet to be released? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can download a blob from the container source by using **account key** or **container SAS Token**. And a blob URI is not supported as source to download the blob.The following snapshot is my test result.

1.Use container as the source and container SAS token. Use the Pattern to select the download blob.

```
AzCopy /Source:https://mystorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer /Dest:C:\myfolder /SourceSAS:"?st=2016-11-24T02%3A34%3A00Z&se=2016-11-25T02%3A34%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=c&sig=[s‌​ignature]" /Pattern:blobName
```

[image]

2.Use container as the source and account key token.It also can work. If I use the wrong key token (connectionstring),then I get `"The supplied storage key (SourceKey) is not a valid Base64 string"` error

[image]

3.Use container as the source and blob SAS token, it doesn't work

[image]

4.Use blob as the source and container SAS token, it doesn't support with no pattern

[image]

**[Update]**

We can use [azure storage .Net  SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) to download the blob from the blob uri with the blob SAS Token.

```
StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("blob sas token");//without "?"
            var blobName = "blobName";
            var downloadFolder = @"c:\filefolder";
            var filePath = Path.Combine(downloadFolder, blobName);
            CloudBlockBlob sourceBlockBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri("blob url"), storageCredentials);
            sourceBlockBlob.DownloadToFile(filePath, FileMode.Create);
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for running through those scenarios - it clarifies things. However, only example 3 applies to my case. I am indeed trying to download using a Blob SAS URI.

Comment: According to the AzCopy [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#blob-download), there is no command to support to download single blob with Blob URI via Blob SAS Token by AzCopy tools

Comment: Maybe there is a workaround that we can use azure storage .NET SDK to do that. Demo code please refer to update.

Comment: Hi Tom, actually we've already written a client doing downloads using Blob SAS URI's. We were just looking to compare performance between our implementation, AzCopy, the Azure CLI and blobxfer. I was expecting AzCopy to work the same as blobxfer.